# Can Hive/Alveus consume Wolverine/Deadpool

Tags: marvel, wolverine, agents-of-shield, deadpool

**Foreword**

I am going to call Hive/Alveus Alveus.

When referencing Deadpool/Wolverine, I am actually referencing **Mutants with regenerative abilities**.

I will use the term **Consume** to refer to Alveus's power to consume a human to regenerate himself.

I will use the term **Possess** to refer to Alveus using a dead human body to host himself.

**End of Foreword**

**What would happen if Alveus attempted to consume Deadpool/Wolverine?**

I assume that Alveus can posses and consume Deadpool/Wolverine. They are not Inhumans which is the only condition that has to be met for consumption and possession. I assume that possession might be more complicated as they need to be dead; not only are they hard to kill, they will also put up a fight :). Furthermore, since Alveus can regenerate as well, the use of Deadpool/Wolverine seems a bit redundant. Perhaps the mechanics of Deadpool/Wolverine's regeneration is better than Alveus's ability.

For Alveus to consume a body, it appears that there are only two conditions that must be met:

1. The consumed must be human
2. The consumed must be alive

I am not sure what the mechanics of Alveus's consumption ability is. I believe that Alveus controls parasites that eat the flesh of the human. The parasites return the nutrients or themselves to Alveus.

I imagine that if Alveus were to attempt to consume Deadpool/Wolverine, that the parasites would consume while Deadpool/Wolverine would regenerate. (similar to Wolverine vs Phoenix in *X-Men Last Stand*).

I also imagine their is no canon answer to this question.

Comment: I am voting to close this as POB, since Agents of SHIELD and Wolverine exist in different fictional universes. As you say, there is no canon answer. If Hive also exists in comics, *and* has the same abilities as the TV show, an edit to ask about the comics universe might make this answerable.

Comment: @Adamant I did not think that Wolverine and Agents of SHIELD existed in two different universes as they were both Marvel. My bad.

Comment: Interesting question. Also, just replace Wolverine with the Hulk and you fixed the different universes thing.

Comment: a version of hive does infact exist in marvel 616 continuity http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hive_(Earth-616) though it/they does have a different origin story and slightly different power-set compared to the AOS version it can still consume human flesh.